# Break out of mouse movement according to user behavior

Tags: autohotkey

Below script moves mouse key to different positions of screen at 15 second intervals within an infinite loop :

```
Loop
{
MouseMove, 200, 100, 50, R
Sleep, 15000
MouseMove, -200, -100, 50, R
Sleep, 10000
}
```

How can I break out of this loop when manual mouse movement by user is detected ?

Comment: Did you find an answer that worked?

Comment: @blackholyman yes, ive accepted answer

Comment: Glad you found something that worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe sth like this:  (**reedited** 21.01.2015)

```
F1::
Loop
{
MouseGetPos, X0, Y0
MouseMove, 200, 100, 50, R
    GoSub, BreakLoop
MouseMove, -200, -100, 50, R
    GoSub, BreakLoop
}
return

BreakLoop:
Loop,  1000
{
    Sleep, 15
    MouseGetPos, X1, Y1
    If (X1-X0>200 || X0-X1>200 || Y1-Y0>100 || Y0-Y1>100)
        exit
}
return

Esc::ExitApp
```

Comment: how is that a better answer than one i provided? Why the extra logic to determine positions ... ? Perhaps I have overlooked something in my solution?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question at the point: "when manual mouse movement is detected". 
If you will that this movement is detected by the script you have to determine positions, I think

Answer (score 1):

You can use [A_TimeIdlePhysical](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Variables.htm#User_Idle_Time) but remember that you need to install the mouse-hook to use it.

#### Here's a simple example:

```
#InstallMouseHook
loop,
{
    MouseMove, 100, 500
    sleep 15000
    if (A_TimeIdlePhysical <= 15000) ; if the mouse was moved while the script was sleeping
        break
    MouseMove, 500, 100
    sleep 10000
    if (A_TimeIdlePhysical <= 10000) ; if the mouse was moved within the last 10 secs
        break
}
return
```

Hope it helps

note: req version 1.1+ from http://ahkscript.org

Answer (score 0):

This is more difficult than I thought.

Below code will break out of loop when <kbd>Esc</kbd> is pressed:

```
   Loop
{
MouseMove, 200, 100, 50, R
Sleep, 15000  ; 15 second
MouseMove, -200, -100, 50, R
Sleep, 15000  ; 15 second
}

Esc::ExitApp
```